Blackjack game loop sometimes hang after standing
For an assignment, I'm making a Blackjack game in Kotlin. The catch is that each player has a player skill that allows them to modify the results of their next draw.
Here is the important game loop:
while (!PlayerOneStands || !PlayerTwoStands)
        {
            // Player 1 turn
            if (!PlayerOneStands)
            {
                if (p1HandNames[0] == p1HandNames[1]) {
                    println("Would you like to split? Enter Yes or No")
                    val splitChoice = scanner.next().toLowerCase()
                    if (splitChoice == "yes") {
                        p1HandNames.removeAt(1)
                        p1Hand = Player.readCards(p1HandNames)
                        PlayerOne.hand = p1Hand
                        PlayerOne.cardNames = p1HandNames // Assuming `CardNames` is the property name in Player for the card names ArrayList
                        SplitPot = betPot / 2
                        SplitHandName = ArrayList(listOf(p1HandNames[0])) // Assign only the first value of p1HandNames to SplitHandName
                    }
                }

                print("${PlayerOne.name}, do you want to hit (h), stand (s), or double down (d)?")
                val decision = scanner.next()[0]
                when (decision) {
                    'h' -> {
                        p1HandNames.add(Player.drawCard())
                        p1Hand = Player.readCards(p1HandNames)
                        PlayerOne.hand = p1Hand
                        PlayerOne.hand = Player.gambleCheck(PlayerOne)
                        PlayerOneStands = Player.checkHand(PlayerOne)
                        PlayerOne.hand = p1Hand
                        println(p1HandNames)
                        if (PlayerOne.hand > 20)
                        {
                            PlayerTwoStands = true
                        }
                    }
                    's' ->
                        PlayerOneStands = true
                    'd' -> {
                        var availableWealth = PlayerOne.wealth.coerceAtMost(betAmount1)
                        PlayerOne.wealth -= availableWealth
                        betPot += availableWealth
                        availableWealth = PlayerTwo.wealth.coerceAtMost(betAmount2)
                        PlayerTwo.wealth -= availableWealth
                        betPot += availableWealth
                        p1HandNames.add(Player.drawCard())
                        p1Hand = Player.readCards(p1HandNames)
                        PlayerOne.hand = p1Hand
                        PlayerOne.hand = Player.gambleCheck(PlayerOne)
                        println(p1HandNames)
                        PlayerOneStands = true
                        if (PlayerOne.hand > 20)
                            PlayerTwoStands = true
                    }
                    else ->
                        println("Invalid choice. Please enter hit (h), stand (s), or double down. (d)")
                }
            }
            // Player 2 turn (dealer logic)
            while (PlayerTwo.hand < 17 && PlayerOne.hand < 21 && PlayerOneStands)
            {
                if(PlayerOne.hand < PlayerTwo.hand || PlayerTwoStands)
                    break
                p2HandNames.add(Player.drawCard())
                p2Hand = Player.readCards(p2HandNames)
                PlayerTwo.hand = p2Hand
                PlayerTwo.hand = Player.gambleCheck(PlayerTwo)
                PlayerTwoStands = Player.checkHand(PlayerTwo)
                PlayerTwo.hand = p2Hand
                println(p2HandNames)
            }
        }

Here are some methods from Player:
fun drawCard(): String
        {
            if (STANDARD_PLAYING_CARDS.isEmpty())
            {
                println("Ran out of cards. Game Over")
                System.exit(0)
                return "No cards left"
            }

            // Generate a random index within the range of available cards
            val index = rand.nextInt(STANDARD_PLAYING_CARDS.size)

            // Get the card type at the selected index
            val cardType = STANDARD_PLAYING_CARDS[index]

            // Remove the drawn card from the list of available cards
            STANDARD_PLAYING_CARDS.removeAt(index)

            return cardType
        }
        fun readCards(french: ArrayList<String>): Int
        {
            var totalValue = 0
            var aceCount = 0
            for (currentCard in french)
            {
                when
                {
                    currentCard == "Jack" || currentCard == "Queen" || currentCard == "King" -> totalValue += 10
                    currentCard == "Ace" ->
                    {
                        totalValue += 11
                        aceCount++
                    }
                    else -> totalValue += currentCard.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
                }
            }
            while (totalValue > 21 && aceCount > 0)
            {
                totalValue -= 10
                aceCount--
            }
            return totalValue
        }

        fun gambleCheck(rngPlayer: Player): Int
        {
            val handValue = rngPlayer.hand
            val randomInt = rand.nextInt(101)
            return when {
                randomInt > rngPlayer.gamblingSkill * 2 ->
                {
                    println(rngPlayer.name + " got unlucky!")
                    val lastCardIndex = rngPlayer.cardNames.lastIndex
                    rngPlayer.cardNames[lastCardIndex] = "10" //Actually changes their hand to match up.
                    handValue + 10
                }
                handValue < 22 -> handValue
                randomInt < rngPlayer.gamblingSkill -> {
                    println(rngPlayer.name + " Got lucky!")
                    var lastCardValue = 0
                    val lastCard = rngPlayer.cardNames.last() // Convert last card name to Int or default to 0
                    if(lastCard == "Jack" || lastCard == "King" || lastCard == "Queen")
                        lastCardValue = 10
                    else
                        lastCardValue = lastCard.toIntOrNull() ?:0
                    val winDifference = 21 - rngPlayer.hand + lastCardValue
                    rngPlayer.cardNames[rngPlayer.cardNames.lastIndex] = winDifference.toString()
                    21
                }
                else -> handValue //This is a safety measure in case nothing else is valid.
            }
        }

        fun resetGame(Play1: Player, Play2: Player)
        {
            Play1.hand = 0
            Play1.winner = false
            Play2.hand = 0
            Play2.winner = false
        }
    }

The problem with the code is that sometimes, (but not all the time), if Player One stands or double downs without busting first; either the dealer draws a card and the program idles, or the program just idles. What is the cause of the idling?
